# IconData not being passed into class instantiation as argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class defined:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemHiddenMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  /// name of the menu item
  final String name;

  /// callback to recibe action click in item
  final Function onTap;

  final Color colorLineSelected;

  /// Base style of the text-item.
  final TextStyle baseStyle;

  /// style to apply to text when item is selected
  final TextStyle selectedStyle;

  final bool selected;

  final IconData icon;

  ItemHiddenMenu({
    Key key,
    this.name,
    this.selected = false,
    this.onTap,
    this.colorLineSelected = Colors.blue,
    this.baseStyle,
    this.selectedStyle,
    this.icon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0)),
              child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                color: selected ? colorLineSelected : Colors.transparent,
                width: 5.0,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(icon),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      name,
                      style: (this.baseStyle ??
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 25.0))
                          .merge(this.selected
                              ? this.selectedStyle ??
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                              : null),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to pass IconData as a named argument `icon`, like so:

```
new ItemHiddenMenu(
          icon: Icons.dashboard,
          name: "Investments by category",
          baseStyle:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), fontSize: 20.0),
          colorLineSelected: Colors.teal,
        )
```

The code runs fine, but the icon doesn't show. For testing purposes I tried to define `icon` inside of the class itself and it works, but then all my instances would have the same icon of course, which is not what I want.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code by passing `IconData` It works, icon is visible.

You might try Passing and `Icon` widget rather than `IconData`

Comment: Thats not a problem, he is passing it as IconData and using it as Icon data.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I get the following error: “Row’s children must not contain any null values”, so I assume the argument is not being assigned correctly for some reason...

Comment: Then the error lies in something else.. A child of row is null.. pin point the error using stack trace

Comment: Post the full stack trace..the error which gets logged

Comment: The thing is that no error is actually raised. I just can't see the icons.@iamyadunandan

Comment: the code runs for me.. Displays the icon I pass.. Change the width and height of the container to actual double like 500 500, check whether it shows